# Get zip of repository in another repository and update it

Tags: git, github

I want to get a zip of  `repository one` in `repository two`. The zip should be updated automatically when something in `repository one` has changed (GitHub preferred).

To create a zip I used `$ git archive -o latest.tar.gz --prefix=project/ HEAD`. But I have to use it every time I make changes in the repository.
Or is there an option to get a zip of git repository and keep the zip packed?

**EDIT**
I used GitHub Actions

```
name: Deploy my zip
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Zip  Folder
      run: zip -r release.zip . -x ".git/*" ".github/*" "src/sass/*"
    - name: Release to Github
      run: echo "Release"
    - name: 'Upload Artifact'
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        path: release.zip
    - name: Download a single artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
```

But can I push a artifact in another repository?

Comment: You could probably create a [github workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) to do something like this (that would be triggered by any commits to `repository one`). Seems like an awful idea, though, because you're going to end up with a matching commit in `repository two` every time the file is updated. This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: And is it possible to get a repo and keep the zip packed?

Comment: The result of running `git archive` is a single commit (possibly with some slight additions, subtractions, and/or substitutions). If you want a repository to get multiple commits from another repository, use `git fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with GitHub Actions. I will build a release.

```
name: Build Release
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*' # Push events to matching v*, i.e.  v1.0, v20.15.10

jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code #Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Generate changelog #Generate Changelog
        id: changelog
        uses: metcalfc/changelog-generator@v3.0.0
        with:
          myToken: ${{ secrets.GIT_PAT_TOKEN }}
      - name: Create Release #Create a lease based on a new tag
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_PAT_TOKEN}} # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
          body: ${{ steps.changelog.outputs.changelog }} #uses the changelog
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```